# Get JSON next and previous object

Tags: jquery, json

How to get next (120), previous (122) object? Currently at  second object, 141. Also, I have control on the JSON format.

```
var articleId = 141;

var url = {
    "Article": [
        {
            "Id": "122",
            "Title": "Article #122"
        },
        {
            "Id": "141",
            "Title": "Article #141"
        },
        {
            "Id": "120",
            "Title": "Article #120"
        }
    ]
};

$.each(url.Article, function (i, data) {
    var current = data.Id;

    if (current == articleId)
        console.log(this.Title)

   //next
   //previous
});
```

Comment: search [forEach in javascript](http://goo.gl/oWOLc), that may help you

Comment: All good method. I'll go the one with null checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, with added verification to check whether a previous or next article exists.

```
$.each(url.Article, function (i, data) {
    var currentId = data.Id;

    if (currentId == articleId)
        console.log(data.Title)

    var previous = i > 0 ? url.Article[i-1] : null;
    var next = url.Article.length > i+1 ? url.Article[i+1] : null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` in your code sample is actually the index into `url.Article` that you are currently on. Using this variable you can easily find the next and previous object.

As an example...

```
var prev = i > 0 ? url.Article[i - 1] : null;
var next = i < url.Article.length - 1 ? url.Article[i + 1] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` refers to the current index that you are in. So you can use `i+1` and `i-1` to refer to next and prev index respectively. Do like

```
$.each(url.Article, function (i, data) {
    var current = data.Id;

    if (current == articleId)
        console.log(this.Title);

   //next
   console.log(url.Article[i-1]);
   //previous
   console.log(url.Article[i+1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var p = $.grep(url.Article, function (data, i) {  
      return data.Id == articleId 
             && url.Article.length === 3 
             ? data : null
}, true), prev = p[0], next = p[1]; 

console.log(prev.Id, next.Id)
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/eb6zs5mq/